# Reconciling Records (Date and Number Value): Given two datasets with multiple features, how to get the most likely match?

Tags: python, machine-learning, match

Say I have two datasets `base` and `payment`.

`base` is:

```
[ id, timestamp, value]
```

`payment` is:

```
 [ payment_id, timestamp, value, gateway ]
```

I want to reconcile `base` with `payment`. The desired result is:

`[id, timestamp, value, payment_id, gateway, probability]`

Basically it should tell me what the most likely `payment_id` is for a given base entry. The matching should consider both datetime and value. I would be satisfied if it only gave the one with the highest probability, but it wouldn't bother me to have a 2nd/3rd suggestion as well.

So far I've read a few things about fuzzy-matching and similarity learning, cosine simality and stuff, but couldn't seem to apply those to my problem.
I thought of doing something *manually* like:

```
for each_entry in base:
    value_difference = base['value'] - payment['value']
    time_difference = base['timestamp'] - payment['timestamp']

    if value_difference <= 0.1 and time_difference <= 0.1:
        #if the difference is small, then tell me the payment_id.
```

The thing is that this looks like a really "dump" approach, there would probably be conflict if there's more than one `payment_entry` matching the criteria, and I would have to manually fine tune the parameters to get good results.

I was hoping to find out a way that was a bit more intelligent and automatic to help reconcile those two datasets.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to approach the problem?

---

EDIT: My current status:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from itertools import islice
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import datetime
from random import uniform

orders = pd.read_excel("Orders.xlsx")
pmts = pd.read_excel("Payments.xlsx")

pmts['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pmts.date)
orders['data'] = pd.to_datetime(orders.data)

payment_list = []
for index, row in pmts.iterrows():
    new_entry = {}
    ts = row['date']
    new_entry['id'] = row['id']
    new_entry['date'] = ts.to_pydatetime()
    new_entry['value'] = row['value']
    new_entry['types'] = row['pmt']
    new_entry['results'] = []    
    payment_list.append(new_entry)

order_list = []
for index, row in orders.iterrows():
    new_entry = {}
    ts = row['data']
    new_entry['id'] = row['Id1']
    new_entry['date'] = ts.to_pydatetime()
    new_entry['value'] = row['valor']
    new_entry['types'] = row['nome']
    new_entry['results'] = []       
    order_list.append(new_entry)

for each_entry in order_list:
    for each_payment in payment_list:
        delta_value = (each_entry['value'] - each_payment['value'])
        try:
            delta_time = abs(each_entry['date'] - each_payment['date'])
        except:
            TypeError
            pass
        results = []
        delta_ref = datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)

        if delta_value == 0 and delta_time < delta_ref:
            result_type = each_payment['types']
            result_id = each_payment['id']
            results.append(result_type)
            results.append(delta_time)
            results.append(result_id)
            each_entry['results'].append(results)

            result_id = each_entry['id']
            each_payment['results'].append(result_id)



orders2 = pd.DataFrame(order_list)
writer = ExcelWriter('OrdersList.xlsx')
orders2.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

pmts2 = pd.DataFrame(payment_list)
writer = ExcelWriter('PaymentList.xlsx')
pmts2.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

Ok, so now I got something. It returns me all the entries with the same value and a timedelta lower than x (in this case 60 minutes). Couldn't make it better to give me only the most likely result, neither the probability that the match is correct (same amount, small window of time). Will keep trying.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is probably to select the base/payment pair that has the minimum difference. For example:

```py
base_data = [...]  # all base data
payment_data = [...]  # all payment data

def prop_diff(a,b,props):
  # this iterates through all specified properties and
  # sums the result of the differences
  return sum([a[prop]-b[prop] for prop in props])


def join_data(base, payment):
  # you need to implement your merging strategy here
  return joined_base_and_payment


results = []  # where we will store our merged results
working_payment = payment_data.copy()
for base in base_data:
  # check the difference between the lists
  diffs = []
  for payment in working_payment:
    diffs.append(prop_diff(base, payment, ['value', 'timestamp']))

  # find the index of the payment with the minimum difference
  min_idx = 0
  for i, d in enumerate(diffs):
    if d < diffs[min_idx]:
      min_idx = i

  # append the result of the joined lists
  results.append(join_data(base, working_payment[min_idx]))
  del working_payment[min_idx]  # remove the selected payment

print(results)
```

The basic idea is to find the total difference between the lists and select the pair with the minimum difference. In this case, I copy the `payment_data` so we don't ruin it, and we actually delete the payment entry once we've matched it with a base and appended the result.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try to implement that. My guess is that this is probably more complex, has more lines of codes, and smaller accuracy then a ML model.

Comment: This is certainly not more complex or has more lines of code than an ML model. What I provided is a nearly complete solution to finding the minimum difference. If the base lists are a one-to-one mapping onto the payments, and the matching criteria are value and time, then this should find the best solution. This function essentially finds the argmin of a cost function defined by list values.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try to implement that soon.